# Conditional probability in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, probability

I think I have end up in a bit of a dead end.

Let's say I have a dataset, which is fairly easy - 
person_id and book_id. Which is pretty much factual table that says person X bought books A, B and C.

I know how to find out how many persons have bought Book X and Book Y together.
This is

```
select a.book_id as B1, b.book_id as B2, count(b.person_id) as 
Bought_Together
from dbo.data a 
cross join dbo.data b
where a.book_id != b.book_id and a.person_id = b.person_id
group by a.book_id, b.book_id
```

Yet again this is where my brain decided to shut down. I know that I would probably need to do it so that
`count(b.person_id) / all the people that bought book A * 100`
but im not entirely sure.

I hope I was clear enough.

EDIT1: I'm using SQL Server 2017 currently, so i think the correct answer is T-SQL?.
In the end the format should be something similliar to this. Also there is no cases where person A could have bought three copies of book X.

```
Book1 Book2 HowManyPeopleBoughtBook2
1     2     50%
1     3     7%
2     3     15%
2     1     40%
3     1     60%
3     2     20%
```

EDIT2: Let it be said there is hundreds of thousands of rows in the database. Yes this is bit related to a data science course i am taking - hence huge amounts of data.

Comment: Telling us what database you're using (name and version) would help

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for reminding. Updated.

Comment: Damn, just saw edits. Do you have a table listing all the books?

Comment: Exactly. I have a whole long table, where all of the ids are just ints.
It goes so that person_id 1 bought books with id 0, 1, 2, 7..  and following that person_id 2 bought books...
Table itself is 780k rows long.

I'm trying to incorporate your answer into the one i'm trying currently myself.
I'm understanding what your query really does so perhaps it helped me few steps further.

Comment: But....... Do you have a table listing all the books (a dimension table).  From which you can generate the combinations of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your logic to do this:

```
select a.book_id as B1, b.book_id as B2,
       count(b.book_id) as bought_second_book,
       count(b.book_id) * 1.0 / book_cnt as ratio_Bought_Together
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by a.book_id) as book_cnt
      from dbo.data a
     ) a left join
     dbo.data b
     on a.person_id = b.person_id and a.book_id <> b.book_id
group by a.book_id, b.book_id, a.book_cnt;
```

This assumes that people buy a book only once.  If there are duplicates, then `count(distinct)` would adjust for that.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly that I tried to go for. I actualy had similliar answers beforehand, but I thought they were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to generate all possible combinations of the pairs of books bought together along with the percentage of the persons who bought that combination the following can help

```
create table data1(book_id int, person_id int)

insert into data1
select *
from (values(1,300)
           ,(2,300)
           ,(2,301)
           ,(1,301)
           ,(3,301)
     )t(book_id,person_id)  

with books
  as (select distinct book_id
        from data1 a
      )
   ,tot_persons
    as (select count(distinct person_id) as tot_cnt
          from data1 
        )
   ,pairs
    as ( 
   select a.book_id as col1 /* This block generates all possible pair combinations of books*/
         ,b.book_id as col2
     from books a
     join books b
       on a.book_id<b.book_id
       )
       select a.col1,a.col2
              ,count(b.person_id)*100/(select tot_cnt from tot_persons) as percent_of_persons_buying_both
         from pairs a
         join data1 b 
           on a.col1=b.book_id  
        where exists(select 1
                       from data1 b1
                      where b.person_id=b1.person_id
                        and a.col2=b1.book_id)
        group by a.col1,a.col2
```

Comment: The percentage is the wrong percentage.  The op wants.. Of those who bought book 1, what percentage also bought book 2.the denominator is dependent on how many people bought book 1, it's not the total set of people.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone, apologies for typo's

```
SELECT
  SUM(bought_b) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    person_id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN book_id = 'A' THEN 1 END)   AS bought_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN book_id = 'B' THEN 1 END)   AS bought_b
  FROM
    data
  WHERE
    book_id IN ('A', 'B')
  GROUP BY
    person_id
)
  person_stats
WHERE
  bought_a = 1
```

On my phone, apologies for typo's

EDIT : just saw that you want all combinations, just just one set combination.

```
WITH
  book AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT book_id FROM data
) 
SELECT
  book_a_id,
  book_b_id,
  bought_b * 100.0 / bought_b
FROM
(
  SELECT
    book_a.book_id    AS book_a_id,
    book_b.book_id    AS book_b_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT data_a.person_id)    AS bought_a, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT data_b.person_id)    AS bought_b
  FROM
    book    AS book_a
  CROSS JOIN
    book    AS book_b
  INNER JOIN
    data    AS data_a
      ON data_a.book_id = book_a.book_id
  LEFT JOIN
    data    AS data_b
      ON data_b.book_id = book_b.book_id
  GROUP BY
    book_a.book_id,
    book_b.book_id
)
  stats
```